# CakePHP (2.4) routes json

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have this in my routes file:

```
CakePlugin::routes();
Router::mapResources('api');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Currently if I call a controller I have Api with .json as an extension as long as it's a HTTP GET (not post) it outputs json which is fine, no matter the method/function name as long as it exists in my Api controller.

If I make a post, whilst I can decode the posted JSON whatever function/method I've called, it errors saying I'm missing xxx.ctp in  app/Api/Views/json/ 
 xxx.ctp = the name of any function I've called to post.

2 Questions/problems.

Ideally I want to parse any request to the Api controller as json, but without having to specify the .json extension in the url.

Secondly, how/why can't the HTTP POST output json like the HTTP GET, do I need to map something else somewhere?

Many thanks

Comment: Your expectation is flawed. The output should always correspond to the filetype / extension. Thus, you always need the json extension for JSON responses. And if you use xml, you get XML, if you use no extension you get HTTP. that is how it should work. Not what you expect. See [AJAX and CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/). And if you only want JSON, make sure all others error (4xx) properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render everything from a specific controller (in your case, ApiController.php) as JSON without requiring the user to append the .json extension on their request, you can use renderAs and setContent in your beforeFilter.

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
       parent::beforeFilter();
       $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json');
       $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    }
```

renderAs and setContent are part of [RequestHandler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html).

This does mean that this controller will never return anything other than json. If your happy with that, you can even remove extension catcher in your routes.php file...

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Remembering that if you remove the above line from your routes.php file, a request to your ApiController of any kind will result in a 404 being thrown (not as JSON).

Developing further using the beforeFilter you can actually render as different content-types depending on the type of request. For example..

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
       parent::beforeFilter();
           if ($this->RequestHandler->isGet()) {
               $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json');
               $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
           }
    }
```

Comment: you don't address the second point (though tbh I don't know what the problem is - not enough detail) +1 for the request handler example.

Comment: Thanks. The code I posted works for both GET and POST requests, resolving the first issue too. Also, I've just extended the answer to contain information on how to handle request types differently, although this was not asked for.

Comment: Cheers, this does infact covert both questions.